# Joining two pandas dataframes with multi-indexed columns

Tags: pandas, join, multi-index

I want to join two pandas dataframes, one of which has multi-indexed columns.

This is how I make the first dataframe.

```
data_large = pd.DataFrame({"name":["a", "b", "c"], "sell":[10, 60, 50], "buy":[20, 30, 40]})
data_mini = pd.DataFrame({"name":["b", "c", "d"], "sell":[60, 20, 10], "buy":[30, 50, 40]})
data_topix = pd.DataFrame({"name":["a", "b", "c"], "sell":[10, 80, 0], "buy":[70, 30, 40]})

df_out = pd.concat([dfi.set_index('name') for dfi in [data_large, data_mini, data_topix]], 
                   keys=['Large', 'Mini', 'Topix'], axis=1)\
           .rename_axis(mapper=['name'], axis=0).rename_axis(mapper=['product','buy_sell'], axis=1)
df_out
```

[image]

And this is the second dataframe.

```
group = pd.DataFrame({"name":["a", "b", "c", "d"], "group":[1, 1, 2, 2]})
group
```

[image]

How can I join the second to the first, on the column `name`, keeping the multi-indexed columns?

This did not work and it flattened the multi-index.

```
df_final = df_out.merge(group, on=['name'], how='left')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need `MultiIndex` after `merge` is necessary convert column `group` to `MultiIndex DataFrame`, here is converted column `name` to index for merge by index, else both columns has to be converted to `MultiIndex`:

```
group = group.set_index('name')
group.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([group.columns, ['new']])

df_final = df_out.merge(group, on=['name'], how='left')
```

Or:

```
df_final = df_out.merge(group, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

---

```
print (df_final)
product  Large        Mini       Topix       group
buy_sell  sell   buy  sell   buy  sell   buy   new
name                                              
a         10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN  10.0  70.0     1
b         60.0  30.0  60.0  30.0  80.0  30.0     1
c         50.0  40.0  20.0  50.0   0.0  40.0     2
d          NaN   NaN  10.0  40.0   NaN   NaN     2
```

Another possible way, but with warning is convert values to `MultiIndex` after `merge`:

```
df_final = df_out.merge(group, on=['name'], how='left')
```

> UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right)
> warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)

---

```
L = [x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, 'new') for x in df_final.columns.tolist()]
df_final.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)   
print (df_final)
  name Large        Mini       Topix       group
   new  sell   buy  sell   buy  sell   buy   new
0    a  10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN  10.0  70.0     1
1    b  60.0  30.0  60.0  30.0  80.0  30.0     1
2    c  50.0  40.0  20.0  50.0   0.0  40.0     2
3    d   NaN   NaN  10.0  40.0   NaN   NaN     2
```

EDIT: If need `group` in `MultiIndex`:

```
group = group.set_index(['name'])
group.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([group.columns, ['new']])

df_final = (df_out.merge(group, on=['name'], how='left')
                  .set_index([('group','new')], append=True)
                  .rename_axis(['name','group']))
print (df_final)
product    Large        Mini       Topix      
buy_sell    sell   buy  sell   buy  sell   buy
name group                                    
a    1      10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN  10.0  70.0
b    1      60.0  30.0  60.0  30.0  80.0  30.0
c    2      50.0  40.0  20.0  50.0   0.0  40.0
d    2       NaN   NaN  10.0  40.0   NaN   NaN
```

Or:

```
df_final = df_out.merge(group, on=['name'], how='left').set_index(['name','group'])
df_final.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_final.columns)
print (df_final)
           Large        Mini       Topix      
            sell   buy  sell   buy  sell   buy
name group                                    
a    1      10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN  10.0  70.0
b    1      60.0  30.0  60.0  30.0  80.0  30.0
c    2      50.0  40.0  20.0  50.0   0.0  40.0
d    2       NaN   NaN  10.0  40.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is it possible to include `group` in the row index? So after the join, I want to have `name` and `group` both in the row index. Your solution gives two levels(`group` and `new`) and I believe it's because the left data frame has two levels. But I want to avoid this `new` so i guess it's better to include `group` in the row index ...

Comment: @MakotoMiyazaki - Not so easy, added solutions.